# clang++ error on late default template parameter declaration

Tags: c++, templates, clang++

The following code compiles fine with g++, but not with clang++ (3.6):

```
// Forward declaration:
template <class S, class T>
struct Base;

template <class T>
struct BaseFriend {
    friend struct Base<int, T>;
};

// Actual declaration:
template <class S, class T = int>
struct Base {
    void foo() {}
};

struct DerivedFriend : BaseFriend<int> {};

struct Derived : Base<int> {
    void foo(int) {
        Base<int>::foo();
    }
};
```

Error occurs in the `Derived::foo` definition:

```
error: too few template arguments for class template 'Base'
    Base<int>::foo();
    ^
test.cpp:3:8: note: template is declared here
struct Base;
       ^
```

Error goes away after few minor fixes, like:

1. If default template parameter is defined in forward declaration instead of actual declaration.
2. Or if `DerivedFriend` is not used.

But, what is wrong with the original code?

Comment: This looks like a clang bug.

Comment: File a [bug report](https://llvm.org/bugs/) -- this is fairly clearly a clang bug, as GCC 4.9, ICC 13, and MSVC 17 (VS2012) all accept the code.

Comment: A bug report have been filed    https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23303

Comment: @Barry, it's strange, as it fails on 3.5 for me as well... (I'm on RadHat 6.3)

Comment: @Barry I've just tried it on Coliru and it gave me the same error...

Comment: @anxieux Ok now I'm just confused as to what I did before. Ignore me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely a clang bug, looks like [#10147](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10147). The standard clearly allows this [temp.param]/10:

> The set of default template-arguments available for use with a template declaration or definition is obtained
>   by merging the default arguments from the definition (if in scope) and all declarations in scope in the same
>   way default function arguments are (8.3.6). *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T1, class T2 = int> class A;
> template<class T1 = int, class T2> class A;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> template<class T1 = int, class T2 = int> class A;
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely in the ballpark of #10147, albeit not identical from looking at that bugreport...